Cant open terminal in Vscode and Android studio
I just try to open terminal in vs code and android studio but  its close right after clicking on it , I googled it but I cant find anything related to this issue , and I cant upload image probably because of internet , help me 

In Vscode have you tried Terminal -> New Terminal or Ctrl + Shift + `
